# Can't delete primary key on table with FULLTEXT index

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I have a table with a primary key that is an `int` data type.  I want to drop this column (as it is unused, and I fear this column may reach the maximum limit of the `int` data type, so we may as well drop it.).

First, I could not drop I tried to first drop the constraint with:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_MyTableID
```

I'm getting the error:

> Cannot drop index 'PK_MyTableID' because it enforces the full-text key for table or indexed view 'MyTable'.

I don't understand this error, because the primary key is an `int`, and I don't think this table has a FULLTEXT index, but if it does, I don't need it.

EDIT:

I was able to drop the column after deleting the FULLTEXT index:

```
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: If you're dropping the only column in the table, why not just drop the table?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that there's no FULLTEXT INDEX on that table?. What does this query return? `SELECT INDEXPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable'),'PK_MyTableID','IsFulltextKey')`

Comment: @Dan: Sorry, I simplified my question by taking out all other unrelated columns; It's not really the only column on the table.

Comment: @Lamak: Well, there's two indexes, both `int`s.  Your query returns `1`.  But...can there be a FULLTEXT index on an `int` column?

Comment: @notfed Is not that the FULLTEXT INDEX is **on** that column, it's that it uses that column to create the key of the index. Hence, you can't just drop the index like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is a full text index on the table. A full text index requires you to have unique key:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx): KEY INDEX index_name
Is the name of the unique key index on table_name. The KEY INDEX must be a unique, single-key, non-nullable column. Select the smallest unique key index for the full-text unique key. For the best performance, we recommend an integer data type for the full-text key.

You can check for a tables full text indexes using:

```
SELECT object_id, property_list_id, stoplist_id FROM sys.fulltext_indexes
    where object_id = object_id('myTable');
```